# Название группы языков, на которых пишут слева направо

Tags: языкознание

Собственно, подскажите, пожалуйста, как называется группа языков, предложения в которых пишут слева направо. Если вообще есть такое название.

Comment: @binixi, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Специальных названий для таких письменностей нет, обычно так и говорят "направление слева направо (буквы в строке) и сверху вниз (строки на листе)" и т.п. Ну неофициальных или разговорных названий может быть много... "Справа налево" часто называют семитским письмом (когда нет опасности смешать с понятием собственно семитского письма - арабов, евреев и других семитских народностей).

Кстати, известны и другие варианты направления исторических письменностей, в т.ч. весьма причудливые.

Answer (score 0):

*Его перо уверенно писало слева направо — **по-европейски** и справа налево — по-восточному.* В. Иванов.

http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lv=x&word=%F1%EB%E5%E2%E0